# SAS, How to run an indexed 'Do" loop through rows?

Tags: sas

I have data in the following form

```
ID  BookingDate  Releasedate
1     1/1/11        1/3/14
2     3/3/12         1/4/17
.
.
.
```

(ID is a character variable)

The data continues on in this way.

What I am trying to do is construct a loop as follows:

```
 If id(i) = id(i+1) AND 
    BookingDate(i) = Bookingdate(i+1) AND
    Releasedate(i) NE  ReleaseDate(i+1)
      Then
       Releasedate(i) = Max(ReleaseDate(i), Releasedate(i+1))
    Else
        Releasedate(i) = Releasedate(i)
```

This would be for i = 1 to (number of rows)

Note, my syntax is psuedo here.

Everything I've read about arrays seems like it works over columns, row by row.

Thanks!

Comment: SAS reads data in from top to bottom one row at a time, so there is no need for the indices in your example. This means however that you can't view the value in front of you (easily), but you can compare with the previous value using the lag() function - http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212547.htm

Comment: What are you actually trying to calculate? Can you describe it in words?  It kind of looks like you want to find the maximum Releasedate within each Bookingdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RETAIN and LAG to find previous values. 
Didn't get a chance to test, but fairly certain this would work. You could probably simplify MAX condition.

```
 Data want;
 Set have;

 Retain Latest_RDate;

 Prev_id = lag(Id);    
 Prev_bdate = lag(bookingdate);
 Prev_rdate = lag(ReleaseDate);

 If Id = (prev_Id + 1) and bookingDate = (prev_bdate + 1) and 
      ReleaseDate ne (Prev_RDate + 1) then  Latest_Rdate = max(releasedate, prev_Rdate, Latest_Rdate);
  Else latest_Rdate = RealeaseDate;

  Run;
```

Comment: Thanks. This didn't quite do the job I needed, but gave me the outline I needed. It's hard working with SAS when used to R...

Comment: They're different programming languages. Quick trick for SAS, think of it as processing it one row at a time, whereas R typically used matrix type math functions. But it generally means the same code works for 10k and 10million rows. If you want R type functionality use IML which is more equivalent to R.